# CalledProcessError on using bash commands in magic cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have used the code below in my Jupiter notebook.

```
%%bash -s "$store_path" "$store_file"
! echo a = $1, b = $2
! cat $1 | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n -s | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | awk '!a[$0]++' > $2
```

This previously used to work flawlessly, and it has been after a long gap that I tried to use this code. It showed the problem as below, about which I have no idea.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-1e2db86b01e6> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '-s "$store_path" "$store_file"', "! echo a = $1, b = $2\n! cat $1 | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n -s | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | awk '!a[$0]++' > $2\n")

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2350             with self.builtin_trap:
   2351                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2352                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2353             return result
   2354 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in named_script_magic(line, cell)
    140             else:
    141                 line = script
--> 142             return self.shebang(line, cell)
    143 
    144         # write a basic docstring:

</home/ambijat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-110> in shebang(self, line, cell)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
    243             sys.stderr.flush()
    244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
--> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
    246 
    247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):

CalledProcessError: Command 'b"! echo a = $1, b = $2\n! cat $1 | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n -s | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | awk '!a[$0]++' > $2\n"' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I tried to manipulate by using one line as `import subprocess`, but it does not succeed. Another thing I tried was using `%` instead of `%%` but this also does not work.
Help is needed.

Comment: Fingers crossed I just feel there is an issue with `!`

Comment: I just tried to do `! ls` and even that fails.  Something is messed up with the `bash` cell magic

Comment: 2 problems were figured. 1) do not insert comment in the magic cell at the top as it will give some error. 2) do not use `!` for `echo` and `cat`.

Comment: Thanks for responding: Oh! removing "bang* ! works!  I suggest you **answer your own question**.  I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Once the `%%` are at the top then `!` are not needed in successive lines. Also, from the memory about an old code, the use of `#` for inserting comments at the top inside the magic cell should also be avoided as it also creates some error.